# skspritenode check intersection with child nodes only

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm writing a top down style car game. When i need to check intesection beetween my car and non-physic object on my scene i do a simple:

```
CGRectIntersectsRect(car.frame,object.frame);
```

I works correctly if i check object on the "firs level". If object has a child how i can check intersection with only the child? I try something like:

```
 CGRect rectChild=[object childNodeWithName:@"childnode"].frame;
 CGRectIntersectsRect(car.frame,rectChild);
```

It doesn't work correctly because the `CGRect` returned by `childNodeWithName` is relative to the parent and not to the scene... There's a way to convert this rect to scene coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

Find by myself:

```
CGPoint positionInScene = [_worldNode convertPoint:[[object childNodeWithName:@"childnode"] position] fromNode:object];
```

With this i can retrive the child node position with scene coordinate and then i can recreate a new cgrect to check intersections